# Decrementing iterator from end() iterator in binary search tree

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, binary-search-tree

In a binary search tree, the `end()` member function shall simply return `iterator(nullptr)`, right?  But the node `nullptr` contains no information about its `left`, `right`, and `parent` data.  So how do we decrement an iterator from `end()`?  The following is what I have so far (defined in the `iterator<T>` class).  My `iterator<T>` class has `node<T>* ptr` as its only data member, and my `node<T>` class has members `T value;  node *left, *right, *parent;`.

```
    iterator& operator--() {
//      if (!ptr) what to do???
        if (ptr->left)
            ptr = node<T>::max_node(ptr->left);
        else {
            node<T>* previous = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->parent;
            while (ptr && ptr->left == previous) {
                previous = ptr;
                ptr = ptr->parent;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: You answered your own question -- if you want to be able to decrement (BidirectionIterator), then obviously the `end()` function CANNOT simply return nullptr, or something that just contains a nullptr.  It must instead return a pointer to some sentinel that can be decremented to point at the last element.

Comment: Nullptr suffices if you just want a ForwardIterator that can't be decremented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your iterator to be a bidirectional iterator you’ll need to provide the necessary information to find the last node of the tree in the iterator returned by `end()`. To avoid dealing with a special case just to decrement the `end()` iterator you could use a “secret” node which uses its left pointer to point at the root of the tree. This way the `end()` iterator would simply be a pointer to this secret node: with this approach there is no need for any special treatment in increment, decrement, or comparison.

Since it is generally undesirable to store a node value in the root the usual implementation splits the nodes into a `NodeBase` holding only the pointer needed for navigation and a `NodeValue` deriving from the `NodeBase` and adding the node’s value. The root uses a `NodeBase` member and the iterator type a `NodeBase*`: for the navigation only the pointers are needed. Since only valid iterators are allowed to be dereferenced a `static_cast<NodeValue*>(n)` can be used to obtain the `NodeValue` when accessing the node’s value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of end() being iterator(nullptr) make it iterator(&anchor), where anchor is the member of the containing tree that is used to hold the root beginning and final node pointers. And then to decrement you simply step back to the preceding node (the opposite action to increment).

It does require somewhat more work than simply holding a root node pointer but it also allows begin() and end() to be O(1) operations.